# Значение слова «поли́терный»

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

На одном из форумов спросили о значении слова **поли́терный**. В словарях это слово отсутствует, а в интернете найти не удалось. Только примеры.

Место развертывания ПВП согласуется с комплектующими РВК и отражается в заявках частей **на политерное предназначение граждан** прибывающих в запасе, нарядах, поступающих из РВК, а также в плане взаимодействия в/ч с комплектующими РВК.

**Политерный** ручной набор в наши дни.

**Политерный** план складского комплекса.

Машинопись — **политерное печатание** и размножение текстовых, табличных и цифровых материалов с помощью пишущей машинки.

Comment: Примерно то же самое, что побуквенный. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Да, наверное, вы правы. Но как понять: политерное предназначение граждан?

Comment: А где вы такого монстра нашли?

Comment: @Горевант, на одном из форумов задали вопрос: «Что такое "Деловое и  политерное предназначение граждан?"». Не смог ответить. Хотя и чувствовал, что слово знакомое. Вернее корень.

Comment: Серж, мне понравился Ваш вопрос. Есть два предложения: поставить в заголовке ударение — _поли́терный_ (а то сразу и не поймешь, что за слово) и добавить метку "значение слов". Нет?

Comment: @Римма Михайловна, мой текст в вашем расспоряжении. Мне с т/ф тяжело будет исправлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://gazeta-pravo.ru/kategoriya-v-v-voennom-bilete-ili-ogranichenno-goden-k-voennoj-sluzhbe/

Из этого материала следует, что призывников делят на категории годности к разным видам службы (буквы и цифры проставляются в военном билете), преимущественно буквенные. Эти обозначения иногда именуют "литерами", напр., согласно материалу по ссылке, *литера “Г” – это отсрочка от службы в Вооруженных силах*. Вероятно, в вашем тексте предлагается отражать в заявках от военных частей требования, сколько какой категории им требуется. Соответственно, "**политерное**" у военных может означать "сгруппированное в списки **по литерам**" или "указанное по количеству **для каждой литеры** (= категории годности призывника)".

Answer (score 1):

Походу тут три разных значения.

**Политерный ручной набор в наши дни** - одним пальцем на клавиатуре. Что-то такое

**Политерный план складского комплекса** - каждое помещение обозначено буквой (литерой), причем к этим буквам привязано назначение.

**Политерное предназначение граждан**
Вот тут интереснее.
Я не могу ответить на вопрос без контекста, но коли речь зашла о военных, дополню. В отношении военных могу сказать точно. "Литером" на послевоенном жаргоне назывался специальный талон-пропуск для получения дефицитных товаров в специальных же магазинах и столовых. Литеры были разных категорий - в зависимости от причитающихся благ. Правда обозначались категории, кажется, не  буквами, а цифрами. Хотя, может, буквы там тоже были.
В этом смысле выражение "политерное **снабжение** граждан" может иметь смысл. Но как оно заново родилось через три четверти века после отмены этих литеров, причем с заменой "снабжения" на "предназначение", не знаю. 
Но вероятно, что граждан действительно как-то группируют с присваиванием некой категории годности к выполнению разных задач.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный ответ.